# ¿Cómo inicializar un Array como atributo de un Objeto?

Tags: java

Tengo una `clase` llamada **Ciclo** donde tengo declarado dos `atributos` de tipo `String`. Y también tengo una `clase` **Main**.

En la `clase` **Ciclo** tengo dos `Arrays`, uno que contiene 7 posiciones y otro con 8 posiciones.

Estoy buscando la manera de inicializar ambos `Arrays` dentro de la clase **Ciclo**, esta contiene sus metodos correspondientes `Get` y `Set`con su `constructor`.

En los atributos de la `clase` **Ciclo** deben de contener en cada posición del `Array` el nombre de una asignatura , pero mi duda es en donde podría inicializarlo.

Se que desde el `Main` podría hacerlo.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Ciclo c1 = new Ciclo ("A","B","C");

    }
}
```

Pero ¿Se puede inicializar desde el `constructor` las posiciones o al incio al declarar el `Array`?

**Clase Ciclo**

```
public class Ciclo {

    private String dai [] = new String [7]; // Ciclo al que pertenece, con 7 asignaturas
    private String asi [] = new String [8]; // Ciclo al que pertenece, con 8 asignaturas

    public Ciclo() {

    }

    public Ciclo (String dai [] , String asi []) {

    this.asi = asi; 
    this.dai = dai;

    }

    public String [] getDai() {

        return dai;

    }

    public void setDai(String dai[]) {

        this.dai = dai;

    }

    public String [] getAsi() {

        return asi;

    }

    public void setAsi(String asi[]) {

        this.asi = asi;

    }

    public String toString() {

        String solucion = "";

        return solucion;

    }

}
```

**Clase Main**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Ciclo c1 = new Ciclo ();



    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Los `array` se inicializan en el constructor sin parámetros

```
public class Ciclo {
    private String dai []; // Ciclo al que pertenece, con 7 asignaturas
    private String asi []; // Ciclo al que pertenece, con 8 asignaturas

    public Ciclo (String dai [] , String asi []) {
        this.asi = asi; 
        this.dai = dai;
    }

    public Ciclo() {
        dai = new String[7];
        asi = new String[8];
    }

    public String[] getDai() {
        return dai;
    }

    public void setDai(String dai[]) {
        this.dai = dai;
    }

    public String [] getAsi() {
        return asi;
    }

    public void setAsi(String asi[]) {
        this.asi = asi;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String solucion = "";
        return solucion;
    }
}
```